# MEAN Stack / How do I create and manage temporary users without a login or signup?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

Okay so I'm currently developing a bit coin related website!

I want it to work like this:

User visits the page and sees a balance of 0.000BTC + a deposit address.

If the user deposits money to that address it shoos up after x confirmations and updates a mongodb doc with the amount they sent.

The user can then make api calls that do stuff with the doc.

Here's what I don't want:

Users to have to sign up to do this...

How can I accomplish this using angularJS or NodeJS?

I was thinking about doing something with sessions / a mongoDB that uses a TTL collection.

However I can't wrap my head around how to do this correctly.

Any ideas, solutions, or example code would be extremely helpful!

-Thanks

Comment: so they deposit btc and once they've lost their session they are gone forever, nice.

Comment: The user would be sent all their bitcoin to their deposit address before their session is gone...

Answer (score 1):

I think that when the money is deposited you should open a user with their deposit email and the ability to update details in his profile later on.
I would send mail confirmation on both deposit and the user profile opened.
That way they don't "sign up" but a user object will be created automatically based on the deposit.
All of this stuff should happen in node BTW (logic and workflow in node, appearance and UX in angular)
Lior